# SQL formatting for percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using the SQL code

```
select table.column, count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over()
from table
group by table.column
```

I would like to use this function for its efficiency since I am working on a large DB. The function generates both values of percentage which sum to 100. I can't figure out a simple way to only generate the true value (1) or value of summed number over number of rows in the column. Is there a simple way I can do this or do I need to use a different function entirely ?

An example data set would be

```
N,  Bit  
0 | 0  
1 | 0  
2 | 1  
3 | 0  
4 | 0  
5 | 1
```

It is a bit, null table where I am taking the percentage of true bits.
The N just stands for Number.

Comment: Can you provide input and output dataset?

Comment: Updated with example. Hope it is more specific!

Comment: Wich DBMS are you using? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: @JoshPart Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio     10.50.1617.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ONLY need to know the percentage of true bits, just do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(Bit, 0)) / CONVERT(Decimal, COUNT(*))
FROM Table
```

If you need to know the percentaje of true bits by other column (N in this case), you need something like this:

```
SELECT N, COUNT(NULLIF(Bit, 0)) / t2.C
FROM Table, (SELECT CONVERT(Decimal, COUNT(*)) C FROM Table) t2
GROUP BY N, C
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM in order to count the True Bits.

```
SELECT
    group_column,
    100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN bit_column<>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS p
FROM myTable
GROUP BY group_column
```

Comment: Having trouble with this as a solution as you can't sum a bit value. Casting seems to ruin results and regardless, my output still generates the 0 and 1 value for percentage.

Comment: Not sure why your conversion does not work. According to this [Data Type Conversion table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) a `bit` column should be convertible to numeric types. Hope it does work with CASE WHEN.